# Firebase Admin Go SDK getting x509 certificate error ONLY when running inside Kubernetes

Tags: firebase, go, kubernetes, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm currently working on a project using the Firebase Admin Go SDK to handle auth and to use the real time database. The project works correctly when I run it locally (by just running `go run main.go`). When I run it in Minikube via a docker image (or GKE, I've tested both) I get this error whenever I try to make any Firestore calls:

```
transport: authentication handshake failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Here is the code I'm using on the server to make the call to the DB:

```go
// Initialize the app 
opt := option.WithCredentialsFile("./serviceAccountKey.json")
app, err := firebase.NewApp(context.Background(), nil, opt)
// This is the first call I attempt to make, and where the error is thrown
// Create the client
client, err := app.Firestore(context.Background())
iter := client.Collection("remoteModels").Documents(context.Background())
snaps, err := iter.GetAll()
if err != nil {
    logger.Log.Warn("Error getting all remoteModels")
    fmt.Println(err)
    return err
}
```

And here is my Dockerfile that adds the service account key Firebase provided me from the console:

```
FROM scratch

ADD main /
ADD serviceAccountKey.json /

EXPOSE 9090

ENTRYPOINT ["/main", "-grpc-port=9090", "-http-port=9089", "-env=prod"]
```

I can't find anything in the documentation about running in Kubernetes.
Is there anything I need to do to be able to connect to Firestore from Kubernetes?

Comment: can you try mapping your app port 8080 to some other port... as I doubt that kubernetes api-server uses that port and because of that the request might be going to apiserver which might be validating the certs.

Comment: @AmanJuneja just tried that and got the same error

Comment: Can you tell me what changes you made.. just curious as it seems more to me that request is going to apiserver

Comment: Sure! I just updated the post so it's easier to read. I just double checked that the port didn't some how get hard coded at some point. From what I can tell looking at the code it should be running on 9089.

Comment: just add 9089 also to the expose line and then give it a try

Comment: No same error, I'm connecting on 9090 to the grpc server

Comment: can you share your pod manifest file?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/diericx/2a4c5198be44bd8d1ade57de51231154

Comment: first thing can you add port 9090 as target port in the service spec. Then as you are using the Loadbalancer service then on minikube there will be no external IP so you will have to reach your app using the node ip and nodeport opened up by the service.

Comment: Okay it looks like [this now](https://gist.github.com/diericx/09228d6d6214b44f03e898adcf45d62c) and I connect by getting the minikube ip and the port for the service (in this case it was 31552) but I'm still getting the error :( I can connect it's just Firebase having issues.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are using alpine based images try running `apk add ca-certificates` it looks like a tls error.
Install ca certificates, it should resolve the issue

Comment: My image is actually empty and running a single binary, you can see it in the post. Do I need an alpine based image to add certs?

Comment: Ahh nevermind! With a swift search I found [an example of a multi-stage build that injects CA certs](https://medium.com/on-docker/use-multi-stage-builds-to-inject-ca-certs-ad1e8f01de1b). This is my [updated dockerfile](https://gist.github.com/diericx/b833e703f0514c0b1d9402452a1d0769).

Comment: Just got back from class and tested it, works perfectly! Thank you so much, just wanted to make sure it also worked in my production env (GKE)